# Read/Write versus Create/Read/Update/Delete permissions difference

Tags: security, permissions, acl

From a practical standpoint, is there any real-world difference between Read/Write permissions and Create/Read/Update/Delete permissions?

It would seem that if a user had the ability to 'create', he should always have the ability to 'update' or 'delete'? If this is correct, then read/write should always be sufficient, and there is no need to store separate Create/Read/Update/Delete permissions?

Are there any real-world use cases in which a user should be given permissions to create but not update, or update but not delete, etc...?

Comment: Could you give more details about the environment? Are you talking about data in a database, on the file system? It would help provide relevant examples.

Answer (score 1):

There are very many scenarios where modification permissions should be partitioned by modification type.  For example, a user might be allowed to create a new log file or append to an existing log file, but not delete an existing log file or modify pre-existing contents of an existing log file.

If your scenario doesn't require partitioning of modification permissions, then don't.  However, if you're not sure whether this might be required in the future, you might want to consider a design that lumps finer-grained permissions into a more general "write" or "modify" grouping that can be used for convenience when the partitioning is not necessary.